# Application/Extension of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f'$ exists and is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f''$ exists on $(a, b)$, where $a < b$. Show that $\exists\ c \in (a, b)$ such that $$f(b) = f(a) + (b - a)f'(a) + \frac {(b - a)^2} {2} f''(c)\ .$$

From experience (though it is very little), my first go at this question was to use the Mean Value Theorem on $f'$, which allowed me to arrive at $$f''(c) = \frac {f'(b) - f'(a)} {b - a}\ .$$

However, I am not sure where to go from here. I also tried to "work backwards", by playing around with the given equation, but to no avail. I believe I need to derive some information about $f$, since $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are in play, but I am not sure what information I can obtain about $f$? A hunch tells me I need to use the mean value theorem on $f$ once more, but I do not know how to proceed.

Any hints or intuitions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

The calculus module I am taking in university is only an introductory one and does not cover Taylor's Theorem, so I believe my professor is looking for another neat way to approach this problem, perhaps simply by using the mean value theorem. Also, this problem appears in the "higher-difficulty" part of the tutorial-in-question, so I suppose the answer is not so straightforward.

Comment: You are right that this result is in the same spirit as the Mean Value Theorem. You might find the similarity of the expression to the Taylor Series expansion useful.

Comment: This is just a special case of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik please see my edit :)

Comment: @zugzug please see my edit :)

Comment: I see that you aren't supposed to know Taylor's theorem yet. However, the most natural proof will be the same, unfortunately, as Taylor's theorem is proved using the mean value theorem.

Comment: @zugzug I see. Could you perhaps provide an answer/intuition as to how I should continue this question using the mean value theorem? In particular, I am not sure how to get $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ to appear.